# Querying a view immediately after writing to underlying tables in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I am having an issue where if I write to a table (**using Linq-to-SQL**) which is a dependency of a view, and then immediately turn around and query that view to check the impact of the write (using a new connection to the DB, and hence a new data context), the impact of the write doesn't show up immediately but takes up to a few seconds to appear.  This only happens occasionally (perhaps `10-20` times per `10,000` or so writes).

This is the definition of the view:

```
CREATE VIEW [Position].[Transactions]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
(
  SELECT
    Account,
    Book,
    TimeAPIClient AS DateTimeUtc,
    BaseCcy AS Currency,
    ISNULL(QuantityBase, 0) AS Quantity,
    ValueDate AS SettleDate,
    ISNULL(CAST(0 AS tinyint), 0) AS TransactionType
  FROM Trades.FxSpotMF
  WHERE IsCancelled = 0

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    Account,
    Book,
    TimeAPIClient AS DateTimeUtc,
    QuoteCcy AS Currency,
    ISNULL(-QuantityBase * Rate, 0) AS Quantity,
    ValueDate AS SettleDate,
    ISNULL(CAST(0 AS tinyint), 0) AS TransactionType
  FROM Trades.FxSpotMF
  WHERE IsCancelled = 0

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    Account,
    Book,
    ExecutionTimeUtc AS DateTimeUtc,
    BaseCcy AS Currency,
    ISNULL(QuantityBase, 0) AS Quantity,
    ValueDate AS SettleDate,
    ISNULL(CAST(1 AS tinyint), 1) AS TransactionType
  FROM Trades.FxSpotManual
  WHERE IsCancelled = 0

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    Account,
    Book,
    ExecutionTimeUtc AS DateTimeUtc,
    QuoteCcy AS Currency,
    ISNULL(-QuantityBase * Rate, 0) AS Quantity,
    ValueDate AS SettleDate,
    ISNULL(CAST(1 AS tinyint), 1) AS TransactionType
  FROM Trades.FxSpotManual
  WHERE IsCancelled = 0

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    Account,
    Book,
    ExecutionTimeUtc AS DateTimeUtc,
    BaseCcy AS Currency,
    ISNULL(SpotQuantityBase, 0) AS Quantity,
    SpotValueDate AS SettleDate,
    ISNULL(CAST(2 AS tinyint), 2) AS TransactionType
  FROM Trades.FxSwap

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    Account,
    Book,
    ExecutionTimeUtc AS DateTimeUtc,
    QuoteCcy AS Currency,
    ISNULL(-SpotQuantityBase * SpotRate, 0) AS Quantity,
    SpotValueDate AS SettleDate,
    ISNULL(CAST(2 AS tinyint), 2) AS TransactionType
  FROM Trades.FxSwap

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    Account,
    Book,
    ExecutionTimeUtc AS DateTimeUtc,
    BaseCcy AS Currency,
    ISNULL(ForwardQuantityBase, 0) AS Quantity,
    ForwardValueDate AS SettleDate,
    ISNULL(CAST(2 AS tinyint), 2) AS TransactionType
  FROM Trades.FxSwap

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    Account,
    Book,
    ExecutionTimeUtc AS DateTimeUtc,
    QuoteCcy AS Currency,
    ISNULL(-ForwardQuantityBase * ForwardRate, 0) AS Quantity,
    ForwardValueDate AS SettleDate,
    ISNULL(CAST(2 AS tinyint), 2) AS TransactionType
  FROM Trades.FxSwap

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    Account,
    c.Book,
    TimeUtc AS DateTimeUtc,
    Currency,
    ISNULL(Amount, 0) AS Quantity,
    SettleDate,
    ISNULL(CAST(3 AS tinyint), 3) AS TransactionType
  FROM Trades.Commission c
  JOIN Trades.Payment p
    ON c.UniquePaymentId = p.UniquePaymentId
    AND c.Book = p.Book
)
```

while this is the query generated by Linq-to-SQL to write to one of the underlying tables:

```
INSERT INTO [Trades].[FxSpotMF] ([UniqueTradeId], [BaseCcy], [QuoteCcy], [ValueDate], [Rate], [QuantityBase], [Account], [Book], [CounterpartyId], [Counterparty], [ExTradeId], [TimeAPIClient], [TimeAPIServer], [TimeExchange], [TimeHandler], [UniqueOrderId], [IsCancelled], [ClientId], [SequenceId], [ExOrdId], [TradeDate], [OrderCycleId], [CycleIndex])
  VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16, @p17, @p18, @p19, @p20, @p21, @p22)
```

and this is the query generated by Linq-to-SQL to check the effect of the write:

```
SELECT
  SUM([t0].[Quantity]) AS [Item2],
  [t0].[Currency] AS [Item1]
FROM [Position].[Transactions] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[Book] = @p0)
AND ([t0].[DateTimeUtc] < @p1)
GROUP BY [t0].[Currency]
```

Also, this is the Linq-to-SQL code that generates the write (using F# type providers):

```
type Schema = Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.DbmlFile<"TradeDb.dbml", ContextTypeName="TradeDb"> 

use db = new Schema.TradeDb(connectionString)
let trade = new Schema.Trades_FxSpotMF()
(* omitted: set object properties corresponding to column values here... *)
db.Trades_FxSpotMF.InsertOnSubmit(trade)
db.SubmitChanges()
```

while this is the corresponding Linq-to-SQL that generates the read:

```
use db = new Schema.TradeDb(connectionString)
query { for t in db.Position_Transactions do
        where ( t.Book = book &&
                t.DateTimeUtc < df.MaxExecutionTimeExcl
              )
        groupBy t.Currency into group
        let total = query { for x in group do sumBy x.Quantity }
        select (group.Key, total)
      }
|> Map.ofSeq
```

I would have thought `System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()` would only return once the write transaction was complete, and that any subsequent query of the view must contain the effect of the write... what am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please paste your linq-to-sql code?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not a F# guru so I'm a bit lost here. I'd try to call the dispose method on the db context (a using statement in c#) used for the insert operation before calling the select query. My guess is that the execution of the insert statement is deferred and sometimes the select statement gets fired before the actual insert takes place.

Comment: The two snippets above are located in two different parts of the codebase, not executed one after the other.  Also, the db context has been disposed courtesy of the 'use db...' syntax.  I don't think this is anything F# specific, this is fairly ordinary Linq-to-SQL.

Comment: Well, I never used F#, but it is obvious, that the writing transaction is not committed yet when you try to read the data back. So, I would check the docs on `SubmitChanges` and verify when and how it commits transactions. It may depend on the garbage collector by default. So, there must be a method in the framework that you use to start and commit transaction explicitly without waiting for garbage collector to kick in,

Comment: The F# part is a bit of a red herring: the call to SubmitChanges corresponds to Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you set the "monitorring select" to read uncommitted ?  Or if it's an iterative process, then add a date/watermark-id for changed records and query up to that ?

Comment: I think it's better idea to just look with sql server profiler what's going on. When each transaction starts, when it ends, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got to the bottom of this: the DB writes are done in their own threads, with the main thread waiting for all the write threads to complete before checking the results.  However, there was a bug in the code which checked whether all the threads were complete, causing the main thread to do the check too early.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your Link to SQL to check the effect of the write is looking at old cached data?  Try refreshing the cache beforehand with the [refresh method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534381%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=fsharp#code-snippet-1) of the context object.  Use `RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues` on the object.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with [table hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) i.e.

```
CREATE VIEW [Position].[Transactions]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
(
  SELECT
    Account,
    Book,
    TimeAPIClient AS DateTimeUtc,
    BaseCcy AS Currency,
    ISNULL(QuantityBase, 0) AS Quantity,
    ValueDate AS SettleDate,
    ISNULL(CAST(0 AS tinyint), 0) AS TransactionType
  FROM Trades.FxSpotMF WITH(NOLOCK)
  WHERE IsCancelled = 0

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    Account,
    Book,
    TimeAPIClient AS DateTimeUtc,
    QuoteCcy AS Currency,
    ISNULL(-QuantityBase * Rate, 0) AS Quantity,
    ValueDate AS SettleDate,
    ISNULL(CAST(0 AS tinyint), 0) AS TransactionType
  FROM Trades.FxSpotMF WITH(NOLOCK)
  WHERE IsCancelled = 0
  ...
)
```

Alos check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx) blog entry, in my case use the nolock hint solve the issue.

Comment: That blog entry shows that using the NOLOCK hint could result in rows being either missed or read twice, which is quite the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score -2):

You have create a view with schema binding

```
CREATE VIEW [Position].[Transactions]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
```

and has 8 union operation with 9 query from 4 tables

```
FROM Trades.FxSpotMF  --2times
  WHERE IsCancelled = 0

FROM Trades.FxSpotManual --2 times
  WHERE IsCancelled = 0

FROM Trades.FxSwap -- 4 times

FROM Trades.Commission c
  JOIN Trades.Payment p
    ON c.UniquePaymentId = p.UniquePaymentId
    AND c.Book = p.Book
```

to refresh the view after each insert into one of these tables that system might required few seconds and your select query run immediately after insertion. 
it might be happened that insert perform within 0~1 ms into table but refresh view take more then 100 ms and select query miss due to view is served from the cache of the server

Comment: But I thought non-indexed views were just a stored query, i.e., nothing is cached?  That is, the result you get from querying a view is identical to inlining the definition of the view into your query?  And if the insert transaction is complete, all subsequent reads should pick up the new value, right?  Or is there some other level of caching I'm missing?

Comment: May be this will help you to explain- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293623.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: That is just discussing caching of complied execution plans, not caching of the results of queries, isn't it?

Comment: check this- what is into cache
[http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43572/how-to-see-what-is-cached-in-memory-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: change your LINQ, select from your inserted table - 
'for t in db.Trades_FxSpotMF do
        where ( t.Book = book &&
                t.DateTimeUtc < df.MaxExecutionTimeExcl
              )
        groupBy t.Currency into group
        let total = query { for x in group do sumBy x.Quantity }
        select (group.Key, total)'
and then check whether it miss or not

Comment: @mpeac, you are right. Querying a non-indexed view is identical to inlining. If the insert transaction is committed, all subsequent reads would see the new value. Indexed, or non-indexed view, it doesn't matter. Only committed or not committed yet matters. So, your F# code must be deferring `COMMIT` somehow.